# finding a universal covering space

Tags: differential-geometry, covering-spaces

I would like to show that given any manifold $M$, I can define a covering space of $M$

I.e., there exists $M'$ and $\pi:M'\rightarrow M$ such that for all $x\in M$, there exists $U_x$ an open neighbourhood of $x$ s.t. $\pi^{^1}(U_x) = \cup_{\alpha\in A}U_x^\alpha$ where for every $\alpha$, $\pi\vert_{U_\alpha}:U_\alpha\rightarrow M$ is a diffeomorphism

My idea is the following:

Choose $x_0\in M$ and define $M'$ as $$M' = \{[\gamma]\ \vert\ \gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow M, \gamma(0) = x_0, \gamma\in C^\infty(I)\}$$

Where equivalence is given by homotopy with fixed endpoints.

On this I will put the following atlas:

given $(U,\phi)$ a map of $M$, choose $y_0\in U'$. Then $\pi^{-1}(U)$ can be "split" into several sets. Indeed, define $$U'_{[\gamma]} = \{[\tilde{\gamma}\circ\gamma]\in M'\ \vert\ \tilde{\gamma}(0) = y_0,\tilde{\gamma}(1)\in U\}$$

Then $\pi^{-1}(U) = \cup_{[\gamma]:\gamma(1) = y_0} U'_{[\gamma]}$

These $U'_{[\gamma]}$ along with $\phi\circ\pi$ will give me my pas of $M'$

Does this work?

Or is there another way of doing this?